# how to keep session in tomcat servers while load balancing?

Tags: apache, session, tomcat, mod-jk

I am trying to make a tomcat load balancing using Apache and mod_jk,
in those tomcat instances there will be some operations that last for 10 hours . how can i guaranty that the same client in the next session will have access to his operations and not another server.
Secondly, if i use sticky sessions , does the client stays every time on the same server ?